# How to fix "LDAPInvalidPortError: Port must be an integer"

Tags: python, ldap, ldap3

I'm trying to connect to a server using LDAP. I've gotten the script to work on a test server that didn't use a specific port number. When trying to connect to our Dev-System, which uses a specific port I receive the following error:

```
File "site-packages\ldap3\core\server.py", line 117, in__init__
ldap3.core.exceptions.LDAPInvalidPortError: port must be an integer
[7836] Failed to execute script ldap_query
```

In the past we used python-ldap which didn't have an issue with a specified port in the ldap.initialize('LDAP://cd-dir...net/(Port)') command. The piece of code that generates the error can be seen below.

```py
def ldap_connect(address, dn, password)
    server = Server(address)
    try:
        conn = Connection(server, dn, password, auto_bind = True)
        print('Authentication Successful')
        print(conn.extend.standard.who_am_i())
    except: LDAPBindError as err:
        print(LDAPBindError)

ldap_connect('LDAP://cd-dir-cd-test....net:port/dc=cd...dc=com', 'user', 'password')
```

To solve the issue I tried taking the port number out of the address and instead put it in the following way:

```py
server = Server(address, port = XXX)
```

That solved the "port must be an integer" error. However, that didn't solve the problem. The new error that I'm receiving is:

```
File "site-packages\ldap3\core\connection.py", line 325, in__init__
File "site-packages\ldap3\core\connection.py", line 340, in do_auto_bind
File "site-packages\ldap3\strategy\sync.py", line 56, in open
File "site-packages\ldap3\strategy\base.py", line 151, in open
ldap3.core.exceptions.LDAPSocketOpenError: invalid server address
[5976] Failed to execute script ldap_query
```

How can I solve this issue? Is there another way to set the port that I don't know of?

Best wishes,

Comment: It did solve the problem. You got past that problem to a new problem. The new problem is now in whatever the content of `address` is.

Comment: I'm not sure if that actually solved the problem. The address is the same string that is used in many other applications so it shouldn't be causing any issues. If I remove the port from the address string I get error 2. If I leave it in, even with port=XXX I get error 1.

Comment: That is not syntactically valid Python code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing an `ldap://` URI to `ldap_connect`, but it looks like the `ldap3.Server` class expects an hostname or address.  That is, you're currently trying to do this:

```py
server = Server('ldap://cd-dir-cd-test.example.net:port')
```

When what you need is:

```py
server = Server('cd-dir-cd-test.example.net', port=port)
```

And of course `port` must be an integer, not a string.  You can use the `ldap3.utils.uri.parse_uri` method to extract the information you want from an ldap URI:

```py
from ldap3 import Server, Connection
from ldap3.utils.uri import parse_uri


def ldap_connect(uri, dn, password):
    parsed = parse_uri(uri)
    server = Server(parsed['host'], use_ssl=parsed['ssl'], port=parsed['port'])
    conn = Connection(server, dn, password, auto_bind = True)
    print('Authentication Successful')
    print(conn.extend.standard.who_am_i())

    return conn

conn = ldap_connect('LDAP://cd-dir-cd-test....net:port/dc=cd...dc=com',
                    'user', 'password')
```